# Bulk Edit Update Multiple Rows in ASP.Net GridView using CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

[you can see VT_AClReport Table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMEOR.png) In the below HTML Markup I have a simple ASP.Net GridView with 3 columns.

First column containing the CheckBox, second column containing a Label for display ID and Access Path of the folder respectively and the third column containing a Label and DropDownList for display and edit status of the folder respectively.

Here I am using GridView with paging to display the data, and the data is about millions of rows. **When I click on submit button to update the checkbox selected rows, execution time is taking too much to update the rows in table.**

For Example: for 5000 rows = 26 min.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue and reduce the execution time to update all the records within few seconds.

Please see the code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvACLReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"CssClass="mgrid" EmptyDataText="No Records Exists..." DataKeyNames="ACLId" ShowFooter="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallback="True" PageSize="500" AllowSorting="True" Visible="False" onpageindexchanging="gvACLReport_PageIndexChanging"                                        EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="mgridalt" />
            <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="10000" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="gridview" HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAllACLReport" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkACLReport" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACL Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblACLId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ACLId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access Path">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblAccessPathACL" runat="server" Rows="3" Width="400px" Text='<%# Eval("AccessPath") %>'ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Directory Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="lblDirectoryName" runat="server" Rows="3" Width="400px" Text='<%# Eval("DirectoryName") %>'ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox>                              
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>


                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Group">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblUserGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserGroup") %>'></asp:Label>                              
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>  
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="mgridheader" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="mgriditem" />
        </asp:GridView>

//Please check this the table contain the drop down list to update the status and submit and clear button 
      <table id ="tableChangeStatus" align="center" width="100%" 
         class="body style1" cellspacing="4" style="border-color: #808080;
         border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; table-layout: auto;" 
         runat="server" visible="False">

               <tr runat="server">
                       <td align="left" runat="server">
                               Status:
                       </td>
                       <td runat="server">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChangeStatus" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                                        runat="server" Width="200px" DataSourceID="SDSChangeStatus" DataTextField="Status"
                                                        DataValueField="StatusId">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDSChangeStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gtsgeneralconn %>"
                                                        SelectCommand="VT_getStatusList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlChangeStatus"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Select Status" InitialValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr runat="server">
                                                <td align="center" colspan="2" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnChangeStatus" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="False" 
                                                       onclick="btnChangeStatus_Click"
                                                     />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnChangeClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" 
                                                        CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnChangeClear_Click"
                                                     />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </table>
```

Code Behind:

```
         protected void ChangeStatusGlobalSensitiveNonSensitiveReport() 
         {
             int rowsAffected = 0;
             foreach (GridViewRow row in gvGlobalSensitive.Rows)
             {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
                    if (isChecked)
                    {
                           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                           {
                                    cmd = new SqlCommand("VT_ACLReportChangeStatus", con);
                                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeStatus", ddlChangeStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACLId", row.Cells[1].Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Text);
                                    con.Open();
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    con.Close();
                                    rowsAffected++;
                             }
                        }
                    }
                    lblUpdatedRowsMsg.Text = rowsAffected + " Rows updated!!";
                    lblUpdateMsg.Text = "Detail Saved Successfully!!";            
                    gvGlobalSensitive.Visible = false;
                    tableChangeStatus.Visible = false;
                    divReport.Visible = false;
                }
                if (rowsAffected == 0) 
                {
                    lblUpdateMsg.Text = "Please select the check box to update the status!!";
                    lblUpdatedRowsMsg.Text = rowsAffected + " Rows updated!!";
                }
            }
```

Stored Procedure

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VT_ACLReportChangeStatus]
    (
        @ChangeStatus nvarchar(50)=null,
        @ACLId int
        )
    AS
    // Exec VT_ACLReportChangeStatus 'Complete',34 
    BEGIN   
    UPDATE VT_ACLReport SET Status = @ChangeStatus WHERE ACLId = @ACLId     
    End
```

Comment: Could you post also Stored Procedure?Can you try to use only one connection? if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 is not needed.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded stored procedure you can check  @Emanuele

Comment: You mentioned somewhere about submitting the page, so where is the Submit button for this?

Comment: What is the primary key on the table `VT_ACLReport` that you are updating?

Comment: I had created ACLID as Indexable key in table and all Update operation are performing with reference to ACLId key only.

Comment: My downvote because I edited this post twice in the same way. Please learn how to format a post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the UPDATE statement in your stored procedure with T-SQL given below.

I am assuming ACLId is the primary key with a clustered index and you have an index on Status column. You would be better off if you create another index on ACLId and include column Status in it since that will really speed up the lookup in UPDATE statement.

In this T-SQL, updates are happening in batches of 1000 records rather than updating the whole data set. You can play around with changing the value of 100 to something like 500 or even less to come up with the best update batch.

```
DECLARE @numberOfRowsUpdated INT = 1000, @maxRowsToUpdate INT = 1000;  

BEGIN TRY    
  BEGIN TRAN

  WHILE (@numberOfRowsUpdated > 0)
  BEGIN

     UPDATE TOP (@maxRowsToUpdate) VT_ACLReport SET Status = @ChangeStatus 
          WHERE ACLId = @ACLId and Status <> @ChangeStatus;

      SET @numberOfRowsUpdated  = @@ROWCOUNT;
  END

  if @@trancount > 0
      COMMIT TRAN

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    if @@trancount > 0
      ROLLBACK TRAN

    -- log and raise error
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks @sunil, I tried with the above T-SQL Query but its taking the same execution time. No difference..Actually i am dealing with check box is selected or not if selected the only query will execute.. thus for each and every row query is running, which is increasing execution time .

Comment: Ok. So same rows could be updated from different grid view rows?

Comment: So for each row, it takes about 26 minutes?

Comment: Not for each row ,to update complete 5000 rows, it took 26 min.

Comment: No same, would not update , i had applied filter before the data come to Grid View. Update will apply only to specific rows only.. but due to execution  of rows one by one increasing the overall execution time.

Answer (score 0):

```
I solved this problem by maintaining View State, Preserving all checked checkbox state and storing in view state.

then concatenating all the id's in one variable.

    protected void gvACLReport_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        PaginateTheData(gv);
        gvACLReport.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        UpdateACLReport();
    }
 protected void PaginateTheData(GridView gvAll) 
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
        {
            list = (List<int>)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvAll.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkReport");

            var selectedKey = int.Parse(gvAll.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

            if (chk.Checked)
            {

                if (!list.Contains(selectedKey))
                {

                    list.Add(selectedKey);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (list.Contains(selectedKey))
                {

                    list.Remove(selectedKey);
                }
            }
        }

        ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = list;

    }

}

    protected void ChangeStatusACLReport()
        {
           int rowsAffected = 0;
            List<int> list = ViewState["SelectedRecords"] as List<int>;
            string ACLId = "";
            if (list != null)
            {
                foreach (int id in list)
                {
                    ACLId = ACLId + id.ToString() + ",";
                    rowsAffected++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvACLReport.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
                        if (isChecked)
                        {
                            ACLId = ACLId + row.Cells[1].Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Text + ",";
                            rowsAffected++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                lblUpdateMsg.Text = "Please select the check box to update the status!!";
                lblUpdatedRowsMsg.Text = rowsAffected + " Rows updated!!";
            }
            else
            {
                ACLId = ACLId.ToString().Trim(',');
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("VT_ACLReportChangeStatus", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChangeStatus", ddlChangeStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACLId", ACLId);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACLId", SqlDbType.NVarChar,-1));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangeStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
                    cmd.Parameters["@ACLId"].Value = ACLId;
                    cmd.Parameters["@ChangeStatus"].Value = ddlChangeStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                lblUpdatedRowsMsg.Text = rowsAffected + " Rows updated!!";
                lblUpdateMsg.Text = "Detail Saved Successfully!!";
                gvACLReport.Visible = false;
                tableChangeStatus.Visible = false;
                divReport.Visible = false;
              //  DeleteCompleteACLReport(ACLId);
            }
```